# Does schema validation always check an XML file for conformance to the XML 1.0 character set?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, character-set

Does schema validation always check an XML file for conformance to the XML 1.0 character set as per:

https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets

...or does it depend on the XML library you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character legality is a matter of XML being ***well-formed***, which is a prerequisite for being ***valid***.

So, it's not schema validation that checks character sets but rather conformant parsing of XML that must occur prior to any validation assessment.

See also [**Well-formed vs Valid XML**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).